# Was Paul literally predicting that God would strike Ananias?

Tags: acts, paul

Related: [Was Paul being sarcastic when he claimed that he didn't recognize Ananias?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/32195/was-paul-being-sarcastic-when-he-claimed-that-he-didnt-recognize-ananias)

From Acts 23:1-3 (NIV):

> 1 Paul looked straight at the Sanhedrin and said, “My brothers, I have fulfilled my duty to God in all good conscience to this day.” 2 At this the high priest Ananias ordered those standing near Paul to strike him on the mouth. 3 Then Paul said to him, “God will strike you, you whitewashed wall! You sit there to judge me according to the law, yet you yourself violate the law by commanding that I be struck!”

Was Paul actually making a literal prediction here? If so, is it known historically what happened to Ananias later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lange's Commentary on the Holy Scriptures, Vol. 9 (of 12 vol. set).

Acts 23 - p. 408

> That prophetical announcement was fulfilled ten years afterwards, when
>   Ananias as one of the leaders of the loyal imperial party, was
>   murdered, at the beginning of the Jewish war, by the insurgents [the
>   *sicarii*]; Jos. *Jewish War*, II. 17.9.